# Непроизносимый согласный звук в слове "шефствовать"

Tags: фонетика, согласные

Ряд источников указывает на непроизносимость "ф" в слове *шефствовать*, например https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/75-russkii_yazyk_v_nachalnoi_shkole/stages/4487-neproiznosimye_soglasnye_v_korne_slova.html

Другие же говорят, что произносится, например https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант верен.

Comment: Приветствую Вас на форуме, *Iurii Popov*! А сами-то Вы как считаете, в какую сторону склоняетесь?

Comment: «Источники» говорят о трудностях произношения. Вы предлагаете варианты трудностей поделить на верные и неверные?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, я это слово не употребляю в повседневной жизни. От других, помню, слышал только произношение _шествовать_. Допускаю, что аналогично слову _чувствовать_ ф не произносится.

Comment: @shampar Недавно опубликовали проект постановления правительства России "Правила русской орфографии". В нём закрытый список случаев непроизносимых согласных. Слово _шефствовать_ под него не подпадает, так что верный вариант всё же планируется один (речь же не только разговорная, есть ещё и экзамены).

Comment: Слово *шефствовать* под чего не подпадает?

Comment: Цитирую:
В группах согласных один из согласных может не произноситься: в сочетаниях стн, стл, здн, рдц, рдч, стц, здц, нтск, ндск, ндц, нтств, стск это средний согласный, в сочетаниях лнц, вств — начальный согласный.